# How to remove .exe folders from pendrive?

Tags: usb-drive

Can anybody help me please, I have inserted pendrive (hp 4gb) & then found three folders portfolio.exe, lecture notes.exe, essay.exe, I format the pendrive & then again opened the file & found no folder is there. But when again i inserted pendrive into my pc & opened the pd, i got three folders are still in pd and not deleted.. I tried many times but not working. now fed up, help me please..**

Comment: Do you have an anti-virus program installed?

Answer (score 2):

You should try to use an antivirus, I suggest you to use [this](http://www.kaspersky.com/security-scan) tool by Kaspersky. It's a free virus scanner and it's really good.

Comment: link not works. APPLICATION IS NO LONGER AVAILABLE FOR DOWNLOAD.

Answer (score 0):

Ever heard about viruses? You need an antivirus. Preferably Avast, and scan your pendrive.
Sadly, your computer might be affected too. So you need to take a backup of your important data and perform a full system scan.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an antivirus. If you are willing to spend the money i would reccomend getting a Norton antivirus software.

here's the link:

http://uk.norton.com/antivirus/